# Generate boolean mask from numpy.where output

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to generate a boolean mask from the output of `numpy.where()`?

Specifically, I would like to use the output of `where` to select values while retaining the shape of the array because further processing needs to be done row-wise, however, `np.where` directly flattens the array without retaining the dimensions:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.random((10, 10))
A[np.where(A > 0.9)]

Out[76]: 
array([0.98981282, 0.9128424 , 0.92600831, 0.98639861, 0.97051929,
       0.90718864, 0.95667512])
```

But what I would like to get is either a (10,10) boolean mask, or the actual values from A, but then in a way that the dimension are identifiable.

My current work around looks like this, but I am not sure whether there isn't a better, more direct, way of doing it.

```
A = np.random.random((10, 10))
B = np.nan * np.zeros_like(A)
C = np.where(A > 0.9, A, B)
```

where I can do the processing for each row separately.

Comment: `np.where(A > 0.9, A, np.nan)`

Comment: That's easier than expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What should be in the positions where `A<=0.9`? Try `A * (A > 0.9)`.

Comment: NIce idea, thanks! Zero would work in my case, but I think generally the reply in the comment of @Mechanic Pig is more flexible, so slightly preferable if zero is no option.